# JQuery: get span element on browser top edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to get the hightest element on the browser view.

my site contains many span elements and when the user scroll i want to receive the element that are on the top of the browser view.

my plan is: save the id of the element and when the user opens the document again it scroll to the latest (the element) position.

Comment: There is no question here. It's not even clear what the point of what you've written is as you have provided no code.

Comment: loop over every element and find its scrolltop..

Comment: Buddy, where are you going to save the ID of the span that is at the top position? Because once you closed this window, that variable will be lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :-

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
var cutoff = $(window).scrollTop();
$('span').removeClass('top').each(function() {
    if ($(this).offset().top > cutoff) {
        $(this).addClass('top');
        return false; // stops the iteration after the first one on screen
    }
   });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shE58/12/)